# Need to open command line task on different thread and monitor

Tags: c#

I'm using windows form and the command line I'm running is time consuming, and meanwhile the GUI is stuck.
I've read all about the background worker and tasks (using framework 4, cannot update to 4.5 to use await), and I can't figure out how to open the command in differnet thread, while monitor the process.tasks.
My problem is I don't know when the process will end, it's an external command line program, so the RunWorkerComplete can not know.

I'm editing my question in regarding to some comments I've received:
Attached is piece of code:

```
static public void Build(string script)
        {
            string Output1;
            var success = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Build1(script, out Output1)); 
           if (success.ToString() == "false")
           // do something
        }

   static bool Build1(string script, out string Output1)
            {
                var output = new StringBuilder();
                bool error = false;
                string line = null;
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                string[] args = { //arguments };
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args);
                p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\somefile.exe";
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                output = //read something
                Output1 = output.ToString();
                return !error;
            }
```

Ok, so basically what it does is invoking an external command line exe file, and show its output in the GUI. Since the I'm passing arguments to the task, I'm using Lambda expression, as shown.
I've shortened the Build1 method, so maybe there are some missing parts here and there.
Nonetheless, it is not working at all. It shown as the task was performed, but nothing happened and the exe file was not fired in different task (obviously, when not using the different thread it works fine...).

Also, any idea how to improve the `if (success.ToString() == "false")`? I don't like it so much... :o)

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What does "while monitor the process.tasks" mean? Please add some code and describe what you've tried, what problem you're getting, and what you're expecting.

Comment: Can you show us how you are running this external application in a blocking manner? Are you waiting for some output back from it or something?

Comment: Your question's pretty broad, but the core seems to be a desire to process the output of a new process asynchronously (i.e. w/out blocking your UI). This involves a number of different techniques all working together, but please see the marked duplicate for a simple example of asynchronously handling process output. If you use the `async` version, it will work directly with your UI; just replace the `Console.WriteLine()` with whatever other processing you'd prefer. If you use the `Thread` version, you'll have to use `Control.Invoke()` to correctly access UI objects but doesn't require `await`.

Comment: As for the last question, I don't really understand it. The variable `success` should have the type `Task<bool>`. I don't see how you can call `ToString()` on that object and get useful information. `Task` doesn't override `ToString()`. I don't see a way to address that question (or even the broader one) precisely without you providing a good [mcve].